# struts2 for modern I performance site

Tags: java, struts2

I want to create a web app and I am looking for the best java web framework to use. The requirements of the app is it needs to handle at least 600,000 user request. Must have a strong security architecture. Iterator very fast and lightweight. I was looking into  Struts2 and it look easy to learn would it  be a good fit for this project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is not only your web application framework that need to be considered here. Struts is surely a light weight MVC based web application framework.  But if you are planning to create a webapp to handle 600,000 requests then you need many other things, few are mentioned here

- Hardware/software load balancers
- Cluster of web servers
- If there are DB interactions for most of the requests then load balance your DBs
- Proper cache frameworks

There may be different options available to address the above points. But be careful in whatever you chose. You may have to run performance checks on different parts/frameworks in your application. This will help you to understand what can slow down your application.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I was planning on using heroku which would provide load balancing and also theiir postgresql solution with hibernate framework

Comment: I am not sure about heroku. But the point is whatever you chose be careful about it. You may have to run performance checks on different parts/frameworks in your application. This will help you to understand what can slow down your application.

Comment: How about the framework is it one worth learning today or is it a legacy framework?

Comment: Are you asking about struts?

Comment: Yes is it something that is being used for modern web application and also does it play well with new web technologies

Comment: Yes it is a good choice but there are other alternatives such as Spring MVC. Check this post and the shared links for a good comparision: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123816/struts2-vs-spring-3